# Justifying Android EditText using JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD

Tags: android, text, layout, android-edittext, text-justify

I have an EditText in my app. I tried to use **JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD** (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout#JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD) To make it's text justified:

```
editor.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
```

It's not working at all, while it's working on simple TextView control:

```
textView1.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
```

It's not documented whether EditText supports justification or not?

I have set my minimum OS to 28, still not working.

Any suggestion on how to justify my editor? No more rich edit features I need.

Answer (score 1):

Even on a TextView, it works only if the text does not have to be a Spannable.
For example, if you set textIsSelectable to true on a TextView, the text won't be justified and is will be an instance of Spanned instead of Spannable.

Which means, I think, if the text layout can be modified in any way, by directly editing the characters in an EditText or by setting text size spans or image spans in a TextView, then it cannot be justified.